# How to make excel save the data when I change the date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-external-data

I d like to input ‘8’ into the attached table (calendar), then adjust the date using the dropdown menu at the top. After changing the date, I want Excel to automatically save the previously entered information and clear the table for the upcoming month or year.

Please also help on how I can fix date example february is less than 30 days.

Thank you

SHeet 1 Months and years drop down

Help Saving info when I change the date and months
Sheets 2

- Help Saving info when I change the date and months

[image: This is the table I am using]

[image: This is the sheet 2 where I store date for the drop down]

EXAMPLE :
I am trying to enter 1 on b9  on july 2024 , then  it will save then when I go to October 2024 the excel will clear for me to enter other input, but I can go back exemple on july 2024 to get back the info I have entered

Comment: I believe you will need VBA to monitor the changed value in the cell

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: for February issue use function "=EOMONTH(D8,0)" that return the last day of month